# Looking for a name for the V-shaped division area between the torso muscles and the leg muscles

Tags: single-word-requests, medical

I am looking for the name of the division area between the torso muscles and the leg muscles. In a photo of muscular men, you literally see a V-shaped division where the stomach muscles reach down to the groin while on either side of those stomach muscles the quadriceps cover the hips. Is there a name for this division between the muscle groups?

Comment: If no doctor has an answer, the answer is that there probably isn't one.

Comment: Have you asked on https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about the English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called the **v-line**:

> The V-shape or line is located where the obliques meet the transversus abdominis muscles. This line can be a physical display of hard work in the gym and discipline in the kitchen. To develop V-cut abs, target your lower abs and obliques. — [Healthline](https://www.healthline.com/health/exercise-fitness/v-cut#:%7E:text=The%20V%2Dshape%20or%20line,your%20lower%20abs%20and%20obliques.)

See also [What is the V-line on a guy's body?](https://www.girlsaskguys.com/other/q699049-girls--what-v-line-on-guy-s-body), where user CarpetDenim provided this graphic:

[image]

Comment: Also known as the Adonis belt, like a "U" with a flange on each side.

Comment: Thank you for all this info! I took this info and searched the internet with these names and found all the info I was looking for.